# Is the Sudbury Slag Pour still a thing?

Tags: sightseeing, canada

20+ years ago I saw the "slag pour" in Sudbury, Ontario. This is molten rock leftover from processing metal out of ore being just dumped down a hillside from special train cars. At night it's really cool:

[image: slag pour]
(from http://www.mysudburyphoto.com/slag-pouring/inco-pouring-slag-PL356.php)

I found YouTube videos from as recently as 2005, yet [Wiki travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sudbury_%28Ontario%29) claims it stopped in the 90s. Who's right? I have a family member going to Sudbury in a few weeks, and if they could safely and legally see a slag pour, I would love to make that possible.

Using [an aerial view on Bing maps](http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=46.468375~-81.045290&lvl=16&dir=0&sty=h&form=LMLTCC), I can see what is clearly a train track with slag billows from it, near Road 55 which is mentioned in the articles saying you can't see it any more. I can't seem to see where it happens now. They used to dump a train full (12 cars) every hour, and I doubt that has reduced much, so it must be happening **somewhere**, right?

Comment: I see you've edited.  Like I said in my answer, it does still appear to be happening just (from that article) "off to the right" of the view (whatever direction that is :/).  And certainly you can fly over it.  I guess it's just less visible now from public land :/

Comment: hm, the view is from the north on road 55, so to the right would be west. I wonder if the combination of the aerial map view and the shots from the article would be educational?

Answer (score 11):

As you've noted, Wikivoyage says:

> This was a highly popular draw all the way up until the 1990s, when
>   the mining company no longer publicized the location of the slag
>   dumps. It is now impossible to view a slag dump from a public spot due
>   to a green reclamation of the slag hills, and it is considered foolish
>   and dangerous to try and trespass onto the grounds.

Indeed, according to a [geocaching site](http://www.geocaching.com/seek/cache_details.aspx?guid=c33d3224-a6cf-46ab-b5ab-ae302e0eef74) that used to go to the public spot best suited for viewing this, the actual pouring has moved as part of re-greening efforts.

However, the slag pours are still happening, and as some have shown as recently as September, it's [possible to fly over the slag pours for a photo](http://miningindustrialphotographer.com/daytime-slag-pour-from-the-air/).

Some mentions on the net appear about business tours, but evidently the [company no longer gives tours](http://www.sudburyminingsolutions.com/greener-pastures-around-vale-incos-sudbury-smelter.html).

However, you could try contacting them directly and see if there's any chance - via [the official site](http://nickel.vale.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It still happens, but in the interior of the pit, so you cannot view it from a public access point.

Comment: Do you have a source, or this just comes out of nowhere? If you've been there, would you mind giving more details?